# How update record for Ajax deletion in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Vehicles_controller.rb**

```
     class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_vehicle, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource

   # skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /vehicles
  # GET /vehicles.json
  def index
    @q = Vehicle.search(params[:q])
    @vehicles = @q.result(:distinct => true).order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new
  end

  # GET /vehicles/1
  # GET /vehicles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /vehicles/new
  def new

  end

  # GET /vehicles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /vehicles
  # POST /vehicles.json
  def create
    params[:vehicle][:name] = params[:vehicle][:name].upcase if !params[:vehicle][:name].nil?
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params)
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all.order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @vehicle.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @vehicle }
        format.js
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /vehicles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /vehicles/1.json
  def update
        params[:vehicle][:name] = params[:vehicle][:name].upcase if !params[:vehicle][:name].nil?

    respond_to do |format|

      if @vehicle.update(vehicle_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @vehicle, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully updated.' }
        format.json {render json: @vehicle, status: :ok}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /vehicles/1
  # DELETE /vehicles/1.json
  def destroy
    @vehicle.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to vehicles_url, notice: "#{@vehicle.name} deleted successfully" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js { render :layout => false}
    end
  end

  def vehicle_search

    @q = Vehicle.search(params[:q])
    @vehicles = @q.result(:distinct  => true).order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(5)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_vehicle
      @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def vehicle_params
      params.require(:vehicle).permit(:name, :created_at, :updated_at)
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= best_in_place vehicle,:name, class: "v_name", id: vehicle.id%></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'.html_safe, vehicle, method: :delete,  remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure to delete <b>\"#{vehicle.name}\"?</b>", commit: "OK" }, title: "Delete Vehicle", class: "btn btn-danger delete_vehicle" %>

    </td>
</tr>       
<%end%>
```

**vehicle.rb**

```
    class Vehicle
  include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :format => {:with => /[1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]{3,}/}
  has_many :pre_processings
  has_many :batch_counts


end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
 $('.delete_vehicle').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
$(".alert").show();
$(".alert").html("Vehicle \"<b><%=@vehicle.name %></b>\" deleted successfully.")
$(".alert").fadeOut(5000);
```

Here i am using destroy.js.erb to delete vehicle name. It works fine.

Here i am using Inline Edit for Best_in_place. After update the Vehicle name, The ajax alert shows previous vehicle name. Not update vehicle name. So how to show updated vehicle name alert.

```
$(".alert").html("Vehicle \"<b><%=@vehicle.name %></b>\" deleted successfully.")
```

The above alert i will show current vehicle name to delete. But if i update using inline edit after i want to delete i'll shows previous record.

Example:

1. Vehicle Name: MH P5 2312 , I want to delete it, The alert shows are you    delete  "MH P5 2312 " Vehicle.
2. After inline edit i will change Vehicle Name: AP 16 1234, So i want to delete  Vehicle Name: AP 16 1234,  but the ajax alert shows, Vehicle Name: MH P5 2312 delete vehicle name.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to update the `alert message` on `ajax request success`

***in your destroy.js.erb***

you should ditch the `.erb` and fetch the car name from an `html element` instead

your `js code` should be as the following:

```
$('.delete_vehicle').bind('ajax:success', function() { 
    var vehicleName = $('vehicle_link').data('vehicle_name');
    // here I assume that you have a link for initiating the delete process and you can add an attribute to this anchor tag element called data-vehicle_name and set its value to the car name.
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
    $(".alert").show();
    $(".alert").html("Vehicle \"<b>" + vehicleName + "</b>\" deleted successfully.");
    $(".alert").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're going to use the `ajax:success` callback (which you don't in this instance), you'll need to bind the `alert` functions to it:

```
$('.delete_vehicle').on('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
    $(".alert").show().html("Vehicle \"<b><%=@vehicle.name %></b>\" deleted successfully.").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Secondly, if you're not getting an updated `@vehicle.name` because - I think - your Rails instance will have already rendered it. I'm not exactly sure why, but the key will be to pass your data through the ajax request ***if*** you were still going to use it:

```
#app/controllers/vehicles_controller.rb
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
        ...
        format.js { render :layout => false, json: @vehicle } 
   end
end 

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$('.delete_vehicle').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {  
    vehicle = JSON.parse(data);
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
    $(".alert").show().html("Vehicle \"<b>" + + "</b>" deleted successfully.").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

--

Bottom line is that `js.erb` is meant to give you actionable Javascript functionality from the controller action. I think your main problem is you're using `ajax` within this, likely causing a conflict.

Above is how I'd use Ajax (IE put the code in the javascript assets folder); if you wanted to use `destroy.js.erb` still, you could use the following:

```
#app/views/vehicles/destroy.js.erb
$("<%= @vehicle.id %>").closest('tr').fadeOut();
$(".alert").show();
$(".alert").html("Vehicle \"<b><%=@vehicle.name %></b>\" deleted successfully.")
$(".alert").fadeOut(5000);
```